# Resizing the Window.Open inside an Anchortag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, window

Im new to Stackoverflow and i am creating a `Window.Open()` that is nested in an Anchortag but when I tried to fix the size and the controls of the `Window.Open()`, I'm getting an `Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token }`

This is my `window.Open()`

```
infoBubble.setContent('<div style="width:250px;"><div style="float:left;"><img style="width:100px; height:100px;margin-right:10px;" alt="Logo" src="/Customer/GetLogo?cId=' + customerID + '"/></div>' + "    <b>" + Name + "</b><br>     " + Description + "<br>Distance: " + distance + " mile <br>" + '<center><a href="/Work/Worker?cusId=' + cusID + '&posId=' + posID + '&locId=' + LocID + '" onclick="window.open(this.href,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=350,height=250);return false;"><span style="font-size: 12px !important">View Profile</span></a></center></div>');
```

Comment: [Debugging JavaScript?](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: @SunilHari so what do you need to make the question clearer? ill provide!

Answer (score 0):

Update your onclick syntax like below.

```
onclick="window.open('this.href','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=350,height=250');return false;"
```

Also `this.href` should be replaced with original link.